# Application not running on Motorola XOOM device

Tags: android

I am developing an Application for Android Tablet, which is running in 800*1280 resolution in 3.0 Emulator. But when I installed it in **Motorola XOOM Tablet** device. it is not running. what could be the reason. 
Thanks.

Comment: There are a billion reasons why it might not be running.  Do you have the LogCat logs?

Comment: Sorry, But i am unable to give LogCat logs. Because Device testing is progress some other place. i am developing it on my System and my Application version is 2.2 and Emulator version 3.0. It is running perfectly on my Emulator screen.  Thanks a lot for your response...

Comment: No-one can help you until you explain in detail what "it is not running" means. It is probably failing due to an exception, and unless you look at the logs you will have no idea what the exception is. Install CatLog on the device, and look at the logs.

Comment: is there any OS compatibility issue with the application???

Comment: Hi all i got the solution, actually it was not the compatibility issue it was resolution issue, for Motorola XOOM Tablet resolution was not exactly 1280*800, it is slightly different for both orientation. Any way Thank you.

Comment: @Himanshu : If you have solve your issue then will you please also help me for thie issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486821/android-motorola-atrix-application-not-installed-issue